# How to create a shapely.geometry.box from a sets of sublist inside a list?

Tags: python, arraylist, tuples, shapely

I have a list of coordinates as follows:

```
zip_box = [(10.0, 20.0, 20.0, 30.0), (28.0, 40.0, 38.0, 50.0), (46.0, 60.0, 56.0, 70.0), (64.0, 80.0, 74.0, 90.0), (82.0, 100.0, 92.0, 110.0)]
```

They are organized as: (minx, miny, maxx, maxy).

How can I convert each set to a `box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)`? When I try a for loop such as:

```
for i in zip_box:
    b = box (i)
```

it throws an error:

```
TypeError: box() takes at least 4 arguments (1 given)
```

I know why, because, tuple goes into two round brackets and assumed to be only one argument. 
I want to convert each set into a shapely box and then get them ready for plotting.

Comment: Maybe `b = box(*i)` is what you want?

Comment: no does not give me the right order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the elements of a quadruple like this:

```
for minx, miny, maxx, maxy in zip_box:
    b = box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
```